# Reactor Flux with blockLast() Spring Boot integration test never spins up

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-boot-test, reactor

I have a Kafka processing Spring Boot app that has a method that runs at application startup (using `ApplicationRunner`) and spins up a Flux that leverages `blockLast()`, because I found that nothing would happen calling `subscribe()`, since it doesn't block the main thread, which I discovered can (and will) complete before the Flux emits any elements.

Now that I'm creating integration tests for this method the problem I'm running into is that the context/app never fully spins up, so my test code is never executed, the app startup just reaches a certain point and hangs forever. When I change `blockLast()` to `subscribe()` the test code runs (though I'm not sure if the Flux code it tests runs correctly this way, as so far I just have a trivial dummy test) and I can see that my primary method with the Flux code is executed. Anyone have any ideas for how I can create integration tests in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and I circumvented it by dispatching the polling task to an executor service as:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.executorService.submit(() -> pollingTask());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to work! I'm using a singleThreadExecutor and my Flux code runs just fine using subscribe() and my integration test runs. However I've started getting this error on startup: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.consumer:type=app-info,id=ihenots-ncp-client any idea why? Still new to Spring and Spring Boot so not sure exactly what's happening or how to add this @PostConstruct method and avoid this issue. Thanks again.

Comment: It's tought to comment on it without looking at the code. You should ask a separate question on it. @PostConstruct can be found in javax.annotation.

Comment: Figured it out. My class implemented ApplicationRunner and I was already overriding run() to execute this method at startup, so it was getting called twice. Got rid of that, am using @PostConstruct to run in a separate thread now and all seems well. Thanks again!

Comment: If the answer helps, consider accepting it so that anyone with comes across the question knows that it's solved.

Comment: Hi, I did try but because I didn't have adequate activity on SO I was unable to, but i just tried again and was able to. Thanks again.